# How can I AJAX POST an array of objects to a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, node.js, object

Is there a way I can ajax post an array of objects and have it parsed on a node.js server? Here is my client side code:

```
var context = [];

obj1 = {
      first_name: 'e',
      last_name: 'e',
      contact_email: 'e',
      contact_phone_num: 'e',
      contact_notes: 'e' 
  }


  obj2 = {
      first_name: 'a',
      last_name: 'a',
      contact_email: 'a',
      contact_phone_num: 'a',
      contact_notes: 'a' 
  }


  var context = [];

  context.push(obj1);
  context.push(obj2)


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/addcontact',
    data: context,
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert('company added!');

    },
    error: function(data, status, res) {
        console.log('err: ' + res);
    }
});
```

My server side code:

```
api.post('/api/addcompany', function(req, res) {
    console.log('add company hit');
    console.log(req.body);  //returns {}
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Right now, when I print the request body it returns `{}`.

Can someone help me access the array of objects properly on the server side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which body-parsing middleware are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you aren't sending an object inside of your ajax post, you're sending an array. Try wrapping the array in `{}` to signify that it's indeed an object, then reference that object property in your server code.

```
var context = []; // array

  context.push(obj1);
  context.push(obj2)


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/addcontact',
    data: {context: context}, // requires an object here
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert('company added!');

    },
    error: function(data, status, res) {
        console.log('err: ' + res);
    }
});
```

Then in your server-side script, you can reference the `context` property of the body object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove one of the `context` variables. There's no need for the second one when you have declared it already at the top.

Second, it seems like you're posting to the wrong url, should it be `/api/addcompany` or `/api/addcontact`?